Confusion about the units of divergence
For a 3-D vector field $V = (u \hat{\textbf{i}} + v\hat{\textbf{j}} + w\hat{\textbf{k}})$:
$$\nabla \cdot V\Big[\frac{m}{s}\Big] = \frac{\partial u [\frac{m}{s}]}{\partial x [m]} + \frac{\partial v[\frac{m}{s}]}{\partial y[m]} + \frac{\partial w[\frac{m}{s}]}{\partial z[m]} = \delta[s^{-1}]$$
If I move to spherical coordinates for a different 3-D vector field $U = (u \hat{\textbf{r}} + v\hat{\theta} + w\hat{\phi})$
where $\hat{\phi}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ are in the direction of the polar and  azimuthal angles, respectively; and each component travels in $\Big[\frac{m}{s}\Big]$ in the direction of their respective spherical coordinate unit vector:
$$\nabla \cdot U\Big[\frac{m}{s}\Big] = \frac{1}{r^2 [m^2]}\frac{\partial u [\frac{m}{s}]}{\partial r [m]} + \frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)[m]}\frac{\partial v\sin(\theta)[\frac{m}{s}]}{\partial \theta[rad]} +\frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)[m]}\frac{\partial w[\frac{m}{s}]}{\partial \phi[rad]} \\
= \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\Big[\frac{1}{m^2 s}\Big] + \frac{\cos(\theta)}{r\sin{\theta}}v [s^{-1}]+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}\Big[\frac{1}{s \ rad}\Big] +\frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial w}{\partial \phi} \Big[\frac{1}{s \ rad}\Big] \\ = \delta [s^{-1}]\Big[1+\frac{1}{m^2}+\frac{1}{rad}\Big]$$
So there are 2 issues here: 1) the units of each term aren't the same so adding them together doesn't physically make sense, and 2) the result should have been in units of only $[s^{-1}]$.
*NOTE: we could convert the $[m]$ distances in the velocity vectors u and v into radians so that they can be more appropriately differentiated with respect to radians, but then we'd be swapping the leftover $[rad^{-1}]$ for $[m^{-1}]$.
EDIT: $\hat{\theta}$ is in the direction of the azimuthal angle and $\hat{\phi}$ is in the direction of the polar angle. I had them flipped

You didn't use the correct expression for divergence in spherical coordinates. Moreover, radians are considered dimensionless so you should ignore them when checking the units. The divergence in spherical units is
$$\begin{align}\nabla\cdot\underline{}\ \left[\mathrm{\frac{x}{m}}\right]&=\frac{1}{r^2 [\text m^2]}\frac{\partial(r^2\underline{}\ )[\mathrm{x\cdot m^2}]}{\partial r[\text m]}+\frac{1}{r\sin\theta[\text m]}\frac{\partial (\ \underline{}\sin\theta)[\text x]}{\partial\theta}+\frac{1}{r\sin\theta[\text m]}\frac{\partial\underline{}\ [\text x]}{\partial\phi}\\
&=\left[\mathrm{\frac{x\cdot m^2}{m\cdot m^2}}\right]+\left[\mathrm{\frac{x}{m}}\right]+\left[\mathrm{\frac{x}{m}}\right]=\left[\mathrm{\frac{x}{m}}\right]+\left[\mathrm{\frac{x}{m}}\right]+\left[\mathrm{\frac{x}{m}}\right]
\end{align}$$
So as you can see, for any vector the units are always correct. In your case $\mathrm{x=\dfrac{m}{s}}$ so
$$\left[\mathrm{\frac{x}{m}}\right]=\left[\mathrm{\frac{1}{s}}\right]$$

I also forgot the $r^2$ in the first term $$\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial \boxed{r^2} x}{\partial r}$$. The key confusion though was not understanding that both degrees and radians are dimensionless, thank you for pointing this out!
